# How to advance row-major and wrap around rows in a Java 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

For a small Java application, I have a constant `SIZE` x `SIZE` 2D char array called FIELD that I am trying to move two objects (represented by char symbols) through. I have two methods in my Field class but one of them does not work correctly.

I want the `moveObject` method to move the given object by a given amount of spaces and wrap around the rows if necessary. Meaning, it the object reaches the SIZE - 1 index in a row, it should move down and continue from 0 in the next row. It should also stop at the SIZE-1, SIZE-1 index and stop it from moving.

My method does not work properly, can you fix it?

```java
public void moveObject(Obj obj, int spaces) {
        // Get the current position of the object
        int oldRow = obj.getRow();
        int oldCol = obj.getCol();

        // Clear the current position of the player on the board
        field[oldRow][oldCol] = ' ';

        // Calculate the total number of spaces moved
        int totalSpaces = oldRow * SIZE + oldCol + spaces;

        // Calculate the new position of the object
        int newRow = (totalSpaces / SIZE) % SIZE;
        int newCol = totalSpaces % SIZE;

        // Update the object's position
        player.row = newRow;
        player.col = newCol;

        // Get the piece of the object
        char symbol = object.getSymbol();

        // Set the new position of the object on the field
        field[newRow][newCol] = symbol;
    }
```

I can also provide the other (display) method of the field or the output of the tests I am running that are also failing as a result.

My objects are jumping to seemingly random locations when I check their locations (row and column) each time after I move them. It should be consistent and wrap around the row as I said.

Comment: `int newRow = (totalSpaces / SIZE) % SIZE;`  What is `% SIZE` doing there?

Comment: When I remove that, I have an ```ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException```. Here is my test: for (int i = 0; i < 70; i += 5) {
            bd.display(obj1, obj2);

            bd.moveObject(obj1, i);
            bd.moveObject(obj2, i);

            System.out.println("Obj1 location: " + obj1.getLoc());
            System.out.println("Obj2 location: " + obj2.getLoc());
        }

Comment: How about `int totalSpaces = Math.max (oldRow * SIZE + oldCol + spaces, SIZE * SIZE - 1);` ?

Comment: What board game is this?  Or, is it an original?

Comment: @Old Dog Programmer unfortunately it doesn't work, I will have to figure something out then :/

Comment: The board game is called ZigZag.

Comment: We don't know what code an `Obj` or a `Player` has. I suggest editing the question to show a [complete but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I have a constant `SIZE` x `SIZE` 2D char array ...
>
>
>
> ... I want the `moveObject` method to move the given object by a given amount of spaces and wrap around the rows if necessary. Meaning, it the object reaches the SIZE - 1 index in a row, it should move down and continue from 0 in the next row. It should also stop at the SIZE-1, SIZE-1 index and stop it from moving. ..."*

Try using just a regular, 1-dimensional *array*.

Here is an example.
It's not exact, and is just a demonstration.

The values *m* and *n* are the *rows* and *columns*, respectively.
And, I'll use *0* to represent an empty space.

The *move* parameters, *m* and *n*, will be the coordinate of the piece you'd like to shift, and *z* will be the amount of places to shift by.

Start by translating *m* and *n* to the indice, *i*, of *d*.
Traverse *d*, starting at *i + 1*, and for every empty space, increase *k* until *k = z*.
Following the traversal, deduct *1* from *j*, if *j = d.length*.
Proceed with another traversal, shifting all values, starting at *j*, to the right, by *k*.

```java
class Grid {
    int m, n, d[];

    Grid(int m, int n) {
        d = new int[(this.m = m) * (this.n = n)];
    }

    void move(int m, int n, int z) {
        int i = (m * this.n) + n, j, k, l;
        for (j = i + 1, k = 0; j < d.length; j++)
            if (d[j] == 0 && ++k == z) break;
        if (j == d.length) j--;
        for (l = j; l >= i; l--)
            if (l - k >= i) d[l] = d[l - k];
            else d[l] = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter f = new Formatter(s);
        for (int i = 0, t, n = d.length; i < n; i++) {
            if (i != 0 && i % this.n == 0) f.format("%n");
            if ((t = d[i]) == 0) f.format(" . ");
            else f.format("% d ", t);
        }
        f.flush();
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is an example, I'll place *6* values, starting at *5 and 2*, and shift them *4* places.

```java
Grid g = new Grid(10, 10);
Arrays.fill(g.d, 52, 58, 1);
System.out.printf("before%n%s%n%n", g);
g.move(5, 2, 4);
System.out.printf("after%n%s", g);
```

```
before
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  1  1  1  1  1  1  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 

after
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1 
 1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

And, here is another example, where I'll place another 6 peices, on row *9*, and attempt to move half of them *10* places.

```java
Grid g = new Grid(10, 10);
Arrays.fill(g.d, 92, 98, 1);
System.out.printf("before%n%s%n%n", g);
g.move(9, 5, 10);
System.out.printf("after%n%s", g);
```

```
before
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  1  1  1  1  1  1  .  . 

after
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  1  1  1  .  .  1  1  1
```